# Connected App with Access to Static Resources

Tags: connected-apps, static-resources

I am working in an org where there is a connected app someone created (not me) that has the Run As user (under Client Credentials Flow) which specifies a user with the system administrator profile. I want to change that to an API-only user.

The app that uses the connected app uploads static resources. If I want to change the "run as" user to an API-only user with a profile with minimal access (i.e., only allowing access to upload static resources), what permissions do I need to grant to that profile? I've looked and don't see anything that fits.

Comment: `Customize Application` according to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_manage.htm&type=5

Comment: How the heck did I not find that when searching?! Interesting: using duck duck go, that page doesn't come up on the first page of results. Using Google I found https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_edit.htm&type=5 as the first result.  Blah. Make this an answer, and I'll happily mark it as such.

Comment: I love duckduckgo for its privacy, but I hate it for its search results. The first page of results are lousy, the second page is irrelevant, and there is no third page. Google may know more about me than I do, but at least I get good search results, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_manage.htm&type=5):

> **USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED**
>
> To create and edit static resources:  `Customize Application`